# index.HTML file is not updating after bower install

Tags: angularjs, gulp, bower

I have added bower dependency of my angular project but those dependency are updating in bower.json file but not in index.html. because of that i'm getting `Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined` error after gulp serve.
I tried `bower install`/ `bower install --save-dev`.

bower.json

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-cookies": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-resource": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-route": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-sanitize": "^1.4.0",
    "angular-touch": "^1.4.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "^1.4.0",
    "jquery": "^3.2.1"
  },
  "appPath": "app",
  "moduleName": "testApp"
}
```

index.html

```
<!-- build:js(.) scripts/vendor.js -->
    <!-- bower:js -->
    <!-- endbower -->
    <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

Answer (score 0):

use your files on priority wise, because in .js, priority is always matter,